# php file, public function, array, adding some css

Tags: php, css, arrays

I have the following php in a public function:

```
[
    'type' => 'text',
    'desc' => $this->l('some information'),
]
```

This code allows the display of the sentence "some information" on a web page.

How could I add any css style to the display of "some information" ?

Comment: Just add some HTML tags and style them with CSS? Maybe I'm not understanding this question.

Comment: Unless we know what `$this` is, or what the `l` method does, this is very hard to answer. You *might* be able to just output HTML with it as-is, but we can't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can put directly the html and add a class or style attribute on your sentence like

```
[
 'type' => 'text',
 'desc' => $this->l("<span class='yourCssClass' style='font-size:20px'>some information</span>"),
]
```

Comment: You should start to upvote and accept solutions if they solve your problem. Till now you've asked 18 questions, accepted only 1 and upvoted 2, not really the way to go about it. @user3278588